How to Set Tab Order for Controls in WinForms Application in the designer or otherwise?
I know this is not original but hear me out.
I’m working on a WinForms application after a hiatus, and I’ve encountered a challenge related to managing the tab order for controls. The application’s screen forms contain numerous controls, and when I need to add a new control in the middle, adjusting the tab order becomes quite tedious. In the good old MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes) days, Visual Studio’s form designer had a convenient feature: you could seed the tab index by Ctrl+Click on controls. However, I can’t seem to find a similar functionality today. By default, we must start from 1.
My question: Is there a way to set the tab order more efficiently in WinForms applications? I’m open to creating an extension if needed, but I’m unsure how to approach this specific problem. While there are plenty of tutorials and examples for various extensions, I haven’t found any information specifically related to Forms designer extensions.
Any guidance or pointers would be appreciated!
I exhausted my search abilities.

View > Tab Order

@HansPassant I know that. It requires clicking on tens of controls and always starting from the first. I would like to "seed" it at any point and the next controls in in the tab order should update position auto-magically.

TabIndex does not have to be a unique number.  So give it the same number as the one above/left to it.  If the tab order is reversed then use View > Other Windows > Document Outline to change the control order.
